# How, or can i query multiple tables in WindowsPhone8 Application using Windows Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

Im using in my wp8 c# application a cloud database trough Azure Mobile Services. I have two tables that i connected with each other with foreign keys.

1. MovieTable (Id,Title,length,genre)
2. EventTable (id,date,movieId)

In my application i can query them separately like the documentation said:

so i can query my MovieTable like this

```
private MobileServiceCollection<MovieTable, MovieTable> items;
    private IMobileServiceTable<MovieTable> Mtable = App.MobileService.GetTable<MovieTable>();
```

then in my method:

```
int selectedId= 13;  // its coming from the user interface, not important now

items = await Mtable
             .Where(mov => mov.Id == selectedId )
             .ToCollectionAsync();

             Movietable tb = items[0];
             txtTitle.Text = td.Title;
             txtlength.Text= td.Length;
```

So what im looking for is to reach all the data parts of the two table like above

```
     items = await Mtable,ETable    (E table is for my Event Table)
             .Where(event => event.Id == selectedId && event.Id =Mtable.Id )
             .ToCollectionAsync();

             Eventtable tb = items[0];
             txtTitle.Text = tb.Title;
             txtlength.Text= tb.Length;
```

and the important

```
             txtDate.Text= tb.date;
```

I know its wrong syntax, but its just for demonstrate what im trying to reach.

in simple sql its looks like

```
 select * 
 from MovieTable m1,EventTable e1
 where m1.id==e1.id
```

So it is possible somehow through azure mobile service ?

Also i know and i already created view in Azure database management portal, but i dont know how can i reach that view in my application, i cannot found any docs about reaching those views.

Comment: You're right - this is absurdly hard, I'm trying to do something myself like this and it's not clear what to do. I thought creating a view would be the way to go, but there is something odd happening with schemas/permissions 'cos I can't see it. I'm going to try a brute force join next... I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

How about implementing a custom API for the mobile service? You can do the table join here instead of dragging everything down to the phone...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/14/custom-apis-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, but I was having the same problem.

You can create a view. I created my view in Visual Studio. Be sure to use the same schema as the tables you are querying or this won't work.

Then create a new table in azure mobile services with same name.

The table won't actually show anything in azure web portal, but you will be able to query just like any other table through mobile services.